# RSSelectionMenu multiple selection is not working after adding model class in it Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using RSSelectionMenu for adding multi-select in my application. It works fine when I add string array. But when I add my model class in it, multiple select feature stops working. It selects all elements when I click on it.

My code:

```
 var filterApiArray: [Model]? = [Model]()
 var simpleSelectedArray = [Model]()

 func multipleFilterSelection() {
    let selectionMenu = RSSelectionMenu(selectionStyle: .multiple, dataSource: filterApiArray ?? []) { (cell, name, indexPath) in
    cell.textLabel?.text = name.county
 }
    selectionMenu.uniquePropertyName = "Model"
    selectionMenu.cellSelectionStyle = .checkbox
    selectionMenu.show(style: .alert(title: nil, action: AppStrings.done, height: nil), from: self)
    selectionMenu.setSelectedItems(items: simpleSelectedArray) { (name, index, selected, selectedItems) in
      print(name?.id, index, selected, selectedItems)
}
```

But if I add a static string array in RSSelectionMenu it works fine. Please comment if anyone works any work around.

Comment: You can map API response in an array and use that array to fill menu.

Comment: @AbdulKarimKhan - How can I do that? Actually I need to show names in the rsselectionmenu and need to get ids after selection . That is then reason of passing model in it

Comment: I am answering how i used it. Please check

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and I am using RS like below:

```
let data = self.arrAgents.map{$0.agentName ?? ""} as [String]
let menu = RSSelectionMenu(selectionStyle: .multiple, dataSource: data) { (cell, name, indexPath) in
       cell.textLabel?.text = name
}
menu.setNavigationBar(title: Strings.AGENT.text)
let selectedData = self.selectedAgent.map{$0.agentName ?? ""} as [String]
menu.setSelectedItems(items: selectedData) { (name, index, selected, selectedItems) in
     // self.selectedTags = selectedItems
}
menu.show(from: self)
menu.onRightBarButtonTapped = { selectedItems in
menu.dismiss()
self.selectedAgent.removeAll()
for item in self.arrAgents{
for selectedItem in selectedItems{
      if item.agentName == selectedItem{
                self.selectedAgent.append(item)
      }
}
}
self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

In above code, data is filled with an array named arrAgent and arrAgent has data from API.

Comment: Here you are selecting same name that you have added in the RSSelectionMenu. But in my case I need to get selection ids when user select some data in the menu

Comment: I have multiple names in my menu.

Comment: Yes that's fine. Suppose you have two keys in your JSON : name, country. You need to show name, but when you select you need to select country.

Comment: Declaration of arrAgents ->  var arrAgents = [AgentModel]()

Comment: yes, but how can we make array of other key items ?

Comment: Look you have a model, in that model you can have other key and from one unique key you can fetch all data of that selected object.

Comment: I am able to get that. Like you I am passing string array in rsmenu. But not able to fetch other keyvalue from that

Comment: My array is not of string type it’s of model and in that model I have more than one key.

Comment: But u are passing .agentName which is of string type. What if you need to get .id in selection ?